# Operator '=' is not Defined for Type Integer in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I am trying to hide rows in SSRS where Sales values are 0 (zero).
My expression is:

```
     =IIF(Fields!SalesYTD = 0,True,False)
```

I am getting the error:
         "Operator '=' is not Defined for Type Integer..."
How do I implement this logic?

Comment: =IIf (Fields ! SalesYTD.Value=0, True, False)

Comment: LOL!
Thank you. How could I miss that?

Comment: Your  Welcome ... bro :)

Answer (score 6):

> Try This..

You Just Missed The `Value` ..

```
=IIF(Fields!SalesYTD.Value=0, True, False)
```

Answer (score 5):

You have a syntax error in your expression.  Your error is telling you that SSRS thinks that the position of your `=` sign is not expected, which usually means you are missing something before it.

In your case, you are missing `.Value` to tell SSRS that you want the value held within the `SalesYTD` field as opposed to other attributes.

Consequently, your expression should be:

```
=IIF(Fields!SalesYTD.Value = 0,True,False)
```